# UISearchBar gives double results when using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, searchbar

What it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvZps.jpg

My textDidChange code:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [_results removeAllObjects];
        [_results addObjectsFromArray:_testphrases];
        isFiltered = 0;
    } else {
        isFiltered = 1;
        [_results removeAllObjects];
        for (NSDictionary *string in _testphrases) {
            for (NSString *key in string) {
                NSString *value = [string objectForKey:key];
            NSRange r = [value rangeOfString:searchText options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
                [_results addObject:string];
            }}
        }

    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_results.count);
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_testphrases.count);

}
```

I am using NSDictionary and looping to use with NSString. When I change `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` to `NSLiteralSearch` this problem disappears, but I need my NSRange to be `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`. Can anyone shed some light on why it gives duplicate results?

Comment: Please provide sample Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Problem in your inner for loop. If the dictionary has more two key value pairs.

```
    NSDictionary *string = @{"name":"Good Morning", "message":"Good testing"};


    for (NSString *key in string) {
        NSString *value = [string objectForKey:key];
        NSRange r = [value rangeOfString:searchText options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [results addObject:string];
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The above loop will run twice. SO you may add same value twice in the Array.